# SO favicon not in Chrome bookmarks

Tags: support, google-chrome, favicon

This weekend I upgraded my Mac from [OS X v10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) to [OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan), and upgraded Chrome to the latest version, 51.0.2704.84. I also migrated my account to a new disk (HDD to SSD), and in the process I lost all the icons in my bookmarks (I used Time Machine as the migration source, and I don't backup cache files). Not a big deal, the first time I go to a site from the bookmark it refreshes the icon.

Except this isn't working for stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com. The favicon shows up correctly in the tab title, but it's not updating in the bookmark. It's working for all my other Stack Exchange bookmarks, just not SO.

I tried deleting and recreating the bookmark, but it didn't help. Any idea what's different about SO/MSO that's confusing Chrome?

UPDATE

This is getting weirder. I tried a few things, and it's gotten a little better.

Restarting Chrome didn't have any effect.

But I logged out and back into my Google account, and the sync seemed to restore most of my bookmark icons. But a few icons remained generic, including these two.

Notably, all my bookmarks that point to questions (which I use for common duplicates) have their icons.

A few hours later the MSO icon came back spontaneously. But the SO icon refuses to come back.

I think the problem may be related to editing the icon URL. The URL I use to go to SO is

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags

When I go to this, it redirects to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery%20mysql%20php%20javascript%20regex%20lisp%20common-lisp%20bash%20linux%20python%20c%20c%2B%2B?filter=need-answers&mode=any

If I bookmark the latter, it has the correct icon. But I don't really want to hard-code all the tags and options into my bookmark, I want to use the simple URL and have SO look up my tags and default settings. So I edit the bookmark and put back the simpler URL and poof! the favicon disappears.

I tried editing other URLs in my bookmarks, generally adding random URL parameters to them that the site ignores. They initially lose their icons, but after I follow the URL the icon is restored.

I think it may be related to the redirect. Another site whose icon isn't coming back is BrowserStack. The URL in my bookmark is https://www.browserstack.com/users/sign_in, but it redirects to https://www.browserstack.com/start#os=OS+X&os_version=El+Capitan&browser=Chrome&browser_version=51.0&zoom_to_fit=true&full_screen=true&resolution=responsive-mode&url=www.google.com&speed=1 (it remembers that I'm already logged in, and redirects to a URL with the last set of parameters I used). Somehow this redirect keeps it from using the site's favicon in the bookmark.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with Chrome sending extra requests for favicons, and those requests being blocked. Have you tried restarting chrome? Perhaps closing it will trigger some sort of cached lookup.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Restarting Chrome didn't help. I've also confirmed that the problem doesn't happen in Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I just found another site that's not updating correctly: browserstack.com.

Comment: Hmm, it's something specific to my account. I can't reproduce it in a vanilla account, and I couldn't reproduce it in BrowserStack. I wonder if it could be related to Chrome syncing.

Comment: I tried signing out of my Google Chrome account, it still didn't fix it.

Comment: However, when I signed back in to my Chrome account, all my other bookmark icons came back except for a handful. And these two are still among the missing.